# Detecting duplicate table name via unit / integration test

Tags: spring, unit-testing, jpa, spring-data-jpa

On a couple of occasions now, as a result of copy-paste, I have created two JPA entities with the same table name. i.e.:

```
@Table(name = "myfirsttable")
public class MyFirstTable { @Id @Column private Long id; }

@Table(name = "myfirsttable")
public class MySecondTable { @Id @Column private Integer id; }
```

I'm using Spring Test, which means that fortunately at least one test fails when I do this. The trouble is that the failures I see will complain about data types. For example, in the above, I would see an exception raised from `HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class` such as `expected int but found bigint` for `myfirsttable`. If I look at the class which is supposed to be `myfirsttable`, I get confused (I'm easily confused), thinking "But it says it's a `Long`, so surely `bigint` is the correct mapping?" It can take me a while to work out why I'm seeing that particular message. Similarly, the stack trace may mention being unable to find a field.

So far, there are only a couple of occasions when I have felt the need to create two differing entities pointing at the same table, so as a means of covering the 99% of cases where two entities pointing at the same table is an error, I was wondering whether there is a simple way to set up a test, which would fail in a way that tells me up front that I have created a duplicate table name. I'm thinking about a single test that I can put into all of my projects, which could give me a useful warning identifying this issue.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 options, that I can see:

You could create a test that will just try and load your ApplicationContext. If that fails something is wrong. Unfortunately to find out what is wrong exactly, you'll have to dig through the logs.

The other option would be to write a test, that will look at all class annotated with `@Table` and see if more than one have the same table name. I use a similar test in one of my projects to make sure that no entity class uses primitives. There are [libriares](https://github.com/ronmamo/reflections) that make it easier to scan for classes with certain annotations.

Comment: Loading the `ApplicationContext` is where I see the current error. The question is more about detecting the likely bug of duplicate `@Table` annotations. I may take a look at scanning for `@Table` annotated classes manually. I wouldn't have thought it would be too tricky...